# Disable try/catch in compiled assembly

Tags: .net

We are using an external API from a 3th party and, from the decompiled code, all their function have a `try/catch` with a empty `catch` statement.

Is there any way to disable try/catch from an external API (in C#)?

Comment: Did you want the API to throw errors instead? Or does it have some other way of seeing error conditions?

Comment: if you want info about the exception thrown (and catched) you can try with [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Also, if you have any kind of support from the vendor, try asking them about it.

Comment: Recompiling the code is not an option here. But I like the `FirstChanceException`. Will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If license allows - Decompile the DLL, modify the exception handling code, recompile back to dll and use it. You can use this Opensource tool for decompiling [ilspy.net](http://ilspy.net)

If not then you could also take a look at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`,
[MSDN Reference Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) This will raise an event for every exception that is thrown in an application domain. So, the `FirstChanceException` event is raised as soon as an exception is thrown.

For a detail explanation with good examples (*like the one I posted here*) [refer to this Post](http://malvinly.com/2012/05/25/net-4-0-and-first-chance-exceptions/).

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First chance exception: " + eventArgs.Exception.Message);
    };

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before exception.");
        throw new Exception("Some error.");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handled.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from decompiling the code, removing all the empty `try/catch` blocks, and recompiling the code, nope.